# How to add a new permanent column that contains result from ST_AREA select queries

Tags: postgis, carto

I have a bunch of polygons in my CartoDB map, and I want to create a new column called `AREA` in the table `MY_TABLE` that contains values from my area calculation query:

```
select ST_Area(the_geom::geography) as area_sqm FROM My_TABLE
```

this statement works, but the column `area_sqm` that contains the area value clears every time I clear the query, how can I have this permanently as part of my table so I can display the area value in the info table of my map?

Answer (score 8):

In general:

```
ALTER TABLE  your_table ADD COLUMN area double precision;

UPDATE your_table SET area=ST_AREA(geom::geography);
```

(If your srid is 4326 and your data is stored as geometry)

**Edit:**

To round to 2 decimals use round() funcrion. If I remember right it works on numeric type and not double precision. So you need something like:

```
ROUND((ST_Area(geom::geography))::numeric,2)
```

Comment: Great! worked! Is there anyway to limit the precision to be just 2 digits after decimal points? Now its showing 9 digits....THANKS!